# Pentaho Kettle - Conversion of a job to jar file

Tags: jar, pentaho

Is it possible to convert a pentaho job to jar file? if it so please tel me how? i tried to convert a job to jar but failed due to the class problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JAR, we aggregate many Java class files. But in PDI Jobs, the files are in XML files. Pentaho uses its DI Engine to read these XML files. Hence we cannot create JAR files out of an XML file.

Answer (score 0):

You can run an ETL job from java code, using kettle's api. You can't convert a job into a jar.

Answer (score 0):

If you launch a job or a transformation in batch mode, you have to use the scripts kitchen or pan (with sh or bat extension dopending on the OS). Actually those scripts run a java program inside, using the parameters that you pass to it. One of the parameters has to be the path of the file .Kjb (extension of a job), which is a regular xml file. So the xml files are necessary, but you can launch directly the java command (the one inside of the sh/bat script) passing the required paramenters to it. To see which parameters it needs you will have to do a reverse engineering work on the kitchen/pan script, which are really simple and short inside.